# Plotting one predictor of a model that has several predictors with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lm

Here is an typical example of linear model and a ggplot:

```
require(ggplot2)

utils::data(anorexia, package = "MASS")

anorex.1 <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
                family = gaussian, data = anorexia)
coef(anorex.1)

   (Intercept)       Prewt   TreatCont     TreatFT 
     49.7711090  -0.5655388  -4.0970655   4.5630627 


ggplot(anorexia, aes(y=Postwt, x=Prewt)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='lm', se=F)
```

My problem is that the regression that is made by `geom_smooth(...)` is not the same model than `anorex.1` but is:

```
coef(lm(Postwt ~ Prewt, data=anorexia))

     (Intercept)       Prewt 
      42.7005802   0.5153804
```

How can I plot the model `anorexia1` on a ggplot?

Could I just take the intercept (49.77) and estimate (-0.5655) of `anorexia1` for `Prewt` and plot it with geom_abline(..), is it correct? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have model that contains two predictors (different intercept values for levels) and also offset variable it won't e possible to directly include it in `geom_smooth()`. One way would be to make new data frame `dat.new` that contains values of `Prewt` for all three levels of `Treat`. Then use this new data frame to predict `Postwt` values for all levels using your model and add predicted values to new data frame

```
new.dat<-data.frame(Treat=rep(levels(anorexia$Treat),each=100),
                    Prewt=rep(seq(70,95,length.out=100),times=3))
anorexia.2<-data.frame(new.dat,Pred=predict(anorex.1,new.dat))
head(anorexia.2)
  Treat    Prewt     Pred
1   CBT 70.00000 80.18339
2   CBT 70.25253 80.29310
3   CBT 70.50505 80.40281
4   CBT 70.75758 80.51253
5   CBT 71.01010 80.62224
6   CBT 71.26263 80.73195
```

Now plot original points from the original data frame and add lines using new data frame that contains predictions.

```
ggplot(anorexia,aes(x=Prewt,y=Postwt,color=Treat))+geom_point()+
  geom_line(data=anorexia.2,aes(x=Prewt,y=Pred,color=Treat))
```

[image]